# Dynamic jQuery selector within object selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am facing problem with dynamic selector. Here is my code

```
var data = {
           'one': {'value': '50,60,70,80'},
           'two': {'value': '10,20,30,40'}
           }
var eachValue = data.one.value.split(',');
```

That code is working correcting but i need dynamic selector for `one` `two` so if i code like

```
var select = 'one';
var eachValue = data.select.value.split(',');
```

its not working. its showing `TypeError: data.select is undefined` error. So how can i use dynamic selector within this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation if you want to use variable as property name so `data[select]`

```js
var data = {
  'one': {'value': '50,60,70,80'},
  'two': {'value': '10,20,30,40'}
}

var select = 'two';
var eachValue = data[select].value.split(',');
console.log(eachValue)
```